# How to manually execute a ruby script file on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a rails application deployed on heroku. There is a script inside the application in the following path

**config/data/create.rb**

On local I just have run the following in the app path:

`ruby config/data/create.rb`

and the script gets executed.

What needs to be done to execute the same on heroku ?

Comment: Already answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543744/how-to-run-a-simple-file-on-heroku

Comment: I followed one of the solution ran `heroku run bash` once done. I executed the file `ruby config/data/create.rb`. Then I get error saying `config/data/create.rb:6:in `read': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - routes.json (Errno::ENOENT)`. When actually the file does exist.

Answer (score 1):

open terminal in your project folder on your local machine. Commit all the changes to git. Push the changes to Heroku using

```
git push heroku master
```

After pushing changes on the same terminal -

```
heroku run ruby config/data/create.rb
```